# cannot remove docker image, error response from daemon

Tags: docker

I'm pretty new to ubuntu so there is probably something simple I am missing.  I am trying to remove my docker images with

```
sudo docker rmi <IMAGE ID>
```

I get the error

```
Error response from daemon: No such Id: 265fdadf...
```

If I try

```
sudo docker ps -a | grep <Image ID>
```

It does not return any results.

I'm not sure what this error response means and why I cannot delete the image.  The Id 265 is different than the actual IMAGE ID of my docker image.

Answer (score 3):

The issue (at least for me) was that in Docker the containers that are exited keep the reference to images, so that those images can't be deleted.  That's why `docker ps -a` is not enough.

So for deleting all the images use these two steps:

```
sudo docker ps -a -q --filter "status=exited" | xargs sudo docker rm
sudo docker rmi `sudo docker images -q --filter "dangling=true"`
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found a dozen `exited()` containers. I don't know why they are still there. They might use a lot disk space (I'm using SSD, holy)

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing containers with images.  When you do `docker ps`, you're asking docker to display the running containers.  When you do `docker rmi` you're asking docker to remove images.  To list the images, do `docker images [-a]`.