# Can't remove image due to error: "Error response from daemon: reference does not exist"

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-container, docker-cleanup

I'm having a strange problem while trying to clear the images created by Docker. This is what I did:

- Remove all containers

  ```
  $ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
  bb3927e956bf
  3e2eeb6287c4
  ```
- Check if there is any container running or created after:

  ```
  $ docker ps -a
  CONTAINER ID    IMAGE    COMMAND    CREATED    STATUS    PORTS    NAMES
  ```
- Remove all images: the first attempt failed because images were referenced

  ```
  $ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
  Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 2f21ea981017 (must be forced) - image is referenced in one or more repositories
  Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 2f21ea981017 (must be forced) - image is referenced in one or more repositories
  ```
- Remove all images using `-f` option:

  ```
  $ docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
  Untagged: dev-php55:latest
  Untagged: reynierpm/dev-php55:latest
  Deleted: sha256:2f21ea981017f65adcf0df3764756690adc35d80538bbb6dcada12990f589f37
  Deleted: sha256:7fbddc1aa50dca9bdf4f8c8033d20eca26ac00432f57333987c0eac3fe55fb08
  Deleted: sha256:15883aeb774feafa64328ea2e77ebbe17a91e79ca1cd8bb2eebca60802fb01f5
  Deleted: sha256:36ff96a995807763e302657eaeb671c000e58e3128a47f63bae543ba501387ed
  Deleted: sha256:053f436f01f809f60ecba9fb961dfb6404dce163f84fbd905eb47a6b436ba50d
  Deleted: sha256:b4525a37a105a199b7e7772de9e6ad86af645509c94c705bd13fbd422bf8f55d
  Deleted: sha256:228092e34fffbb9def7f883eceea9f37fce3750d7a7d5a7551ce009410567240
  Deleted: sha256:a17ed03e91cc4bef074258f731bba0945bcacc78c7ac9f00d88ca111125c94c0
  Deleted: sha256:6118ff18e2049d3e13a903c4163e4e4aceea9fdd30555bdd71a1e23e8d5aa022
  Deleted: sha256:b7347848822645efd3259a6c200a94c7bba15fc72b504c704e39f5db0cdca1a2
  Deleted: sha256:b23b831be841f1f3cececec3e52480723d8312b464d9a89957e867fa695a4eca
  Deleted: sha256:86c4c6d54d9dee52f8abe0ba8b3622b985bce68923dada61838b45860f000f44
  Deleted: sha256:f053241f28e7c62ac77b44ee2f69a7bd6d2bb2ccdd9f916e43b8af88f5865f90
  Deleted: sha256:3f36e15d9aac3c197472d66904fc59bd509ca36c8aa885165aadc6507f27126c
  Deleted: sha256:6586309b23369f2ccb067ca456ebacd1602787960215d7c2e898c28ae6a2e78d
  Deleted: sha256:43d7779d3bcd75a466df309735762f33552c2caf8f656ce1e26e1fd6b0324c49
  Deleted: sha256:9e060bbbad0c042fc45eb52d3e4c41bfd30fb620459f10c62cf7e483d514e1d8
  Deleted: sha256:9da9f4caedc27c128dc51d273f9d1411d6fce3f560c606fff0567d912d2d95e4
  Error response from daemon: No such image: 2f21ea981017:latest
  Error response from daemon: reference does not exist
  ```

Then this error: `No such image: 2f21ea981017:latest` comes up and I should ask, why? Where is such image? There is some kind of internal DB for Docker where it stores information?

After I run all the previous commands then I run the following and notice the output:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              14.04.5             b1719e1db756        3 days ago          187.9 MB
```

But then I tried to remove the images again by running

```
$ docker rmi b1719e1db756
Error response from daemon: reference does not exist
```

And I got the same error, what I am missing here? How I can fix this?

I should add that I've run also the commands from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127807/cannot-remove-docker-image-error-response-from-daemon) but without success.

Comment: FYI. Referring to the error response because of removing images having multiple tags (image is referenced in one or more repositories), it's also an open issue here https://github.com/meltwater/docker-cleanup/issues/19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer myself after some research and the great help from the people behind Docker at Github.

**Summary:** At first I install docker by running the following command:

```
$sudo dnf install docker -y
```

That installed docker from RedHat fork and therefore the version was: `1.10.3`, then using this version I built the image that was causing problems until now. After build the image I remove the `docker 1.10.3` version and switch to `docker-engine` which is the official and install `1.12.1`.

**The problem:** I was trying to remove the image created under docker 1.10.3 but using docker 1.12.1 and from there is where the problem comes from.

**The solution**: remove `docker-engine` and install temporary `docker` in order to remove the images created under such version.

- Remove docker-engine: `dnf remove docker-engine`
- Install docker: `dnf install docker`
- Remove the images: `docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)`
- Remove the docker: `dnf remove docker`
- Install docker-engine: `dnf install docker-engine`
- Build the images from scratch

*Note:* for some reason after I follow every steps as shown above I run into the following issue:

```
$docker images
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.22)
```

Doing a `dnf autoremove && dnf clean all` and restarting `docker` fix the issue.

Feel free to take a look [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26862) if you want more

Comment: Great solution! mine was delete /var/lib/docker folder.

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this problem on docker-ce 17.06/fedora 26. I don't think you need to remove docker, but these commands will delete all your images. So save any images you really need, delete all, and restore your backup;

```
sudo systemctl stop docker.service
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

Comment: The ultimate solution to get rid of a corrupted docker database, which unfortunately occasionally occurs.

Some day in 2017 I pulled a 400 MB MySQL Image inside a CentOS 7 VM with docker-ce V17.

Three years later, I remarked, that I wasn't able anymore to remove this Image with any of the provided tools and options, so the only remaining solution was to wipe the /var/lib/docker directory.